# Keychain From Different Computer

Tags: keychain

I have Macbook Air and Macbook Pro.

I have some notes in Macbook Pro as saved in keychains.

How can I view them in Macbook Air without affecting Macbook Air keychains?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by 'without affecting Macbook Air keychains'.

Comment: I think I can import the keychains from other MBP. But it messes Macbook Air keychains too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iCloud Keychain, you can [store the Secure Notes in iCloud](https://superuser.com/questions/955128/is-keychain-access-secure-notes-saved-in-the-cloud), instead of locally on a machine, and the Notes can be visible on any macOS machine logged into the same iCloud account with iCloud Keychain enabled.